# how to give a specified line specing in UITextField in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, uitextfield

i am using a UITextField with multilines and want to add line specing as i need

how to do so in flex action script;

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be done by using TextFormat

```
var newtextformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

            newtextformat.size     = 12;
            newtextformat.color    = dayTextColor;
            newtextformat.bold     = false;
            newtextformat.align    = "left";
            newtextformat.font     = "Verdana";
            newtextformat.leading  = 5;//here you ca set line specing
            try{
            timetext.setTextFormat(newtextformat,0,timetext.length);
            }
            catch(err:Error){}
            timetext.multiline    = true;
```